# Marketing API Export Async Report ads_insights V2.5

Tags: facebook

I have problems to export Report of  ad's statistics since code written in.NET  Framework **when I use ads_insights (version 2.5).** Before when I used  reportstats with version 2.3  I could download the report succesfully

My request is  **//www.facebook.com/ads/ads_insights/export_report?report_run_id=0000000&format=xls&access_token=token**

When I execute the request in browser I can download the report succesfully (file xls completed), but  when I execute the request since by code .NET Framework  (C#)  I  download the file .xls  incomplete  [enter image description here][2]

### **The tasks to get report are (using code .NET C#)**

**1º request  with method POST**

graph.facebook.com/v2.5/act_countNumbrer/insights?level=ad&time_range=%7B%27since%27%3A%272015-11-02%27%2C%27until%27%3A%272015-11-02%27%7D&actions_group_by=%5B%27action_type%27%5D&fields=campaign_name%2Cad_name%2Cad_id%2Creach%2Cfrequency%2Cimpressions%2Ccpm%2Ccpp%2Cspend%2Csocial_clicks%2Cunique_clicks%2Cctr%2Cunique_ctr%2Caccount_name%2Cactions%2Ctotal_actions%2Cwebsite_clicks&time_increment=1&access_token=token

```
  Result: successful ->  I get a  report_run_id
```

**2º request with method GET**

graph.facebook.com/v2.5/id_report&access_token=token

```
  Result: successful ->  I get a  
    {
      "id": "xxxx",
      "account_id": "xxx",
      "time_ref": 1447171267,
      "time_completed": 1447171269,
      "async_status": "Job Completed",
      "async_percent_completion": 100,
    }
```

**3º when "async_status" is "Job Completed", I execute request**

www.facebook.com/ads/ads_insights/export_report?report_run_id=xxxx&format=xls&access_token=token

Result: I download the file .xls incomplete. If you paste the query (URL) in browser you download the report succesful (file xls completed) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pR7uw.png)

If I execute the request with code .NET Framework (C#) and saved the response as string the response said we "should update your browser "   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3BVP.png)

Why can't I download the report ?

Thank you

**Code using to execute the download the report XLS**

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.IO;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Net;
            using System.Text;
            using System.Threading.Tasks;
            using System.Xml;

            namespace test
            {
                class Program
                {
                    static void Main(string[] args)
                    {

                       string token="token";
                       string report_run_id="report_number";
                        string url = "https://www.facebook.com/ads/ads_insights/export_report?report_run_id="+report_run_id+"format=xls&access_token"+token;

                        //option 1
                        string reportDownloadUrl = "repo"+DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".xls";        ;
                        Stream responseStream = null;
                        try
                        {
                            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                            request.Method = "GET";
                            //request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)";
                            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();              

                            responseStream = response.GetResponseStream(); //relleno el flujo

                            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(reportDownloadUrl, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                            {
                                responseStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                            }                       

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }
                         finally
                        {
                            if (responseStream != null) responseStream.Close();

                        }

                       Console.WriteLine("File Download" +reportDownloadUrl);         


                       /* //option 2
                        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                        {
                            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                             wc.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)";
                             wc.DownloadFile(url,"repo.xls");
                        }
                            Console.WriteLine("File Download");                       
                           */


                        Console.ReadKey();




                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: How are you downloading the file? Can you edit your post with the code you are using to execute the download? Why don't you just have people open that link in a new tab?

Comment: Referring to the documentation here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/v2.4, you need to "link" to the specified URL to export the report.

Provide the link for the end-user to click  isn't the solution succesfully, I need that the application  download the file .xls automatically.  The insights interface to retrieve an ad's statistics can't  be helpful if the application can't download the report automatically

With version 2.3 was possible download the file .XLS automatically, now not it isn't possible. How can I download the file .XLS automatically now?
Regards,

Comment: Have you stepped through your code? I don't think anything has changed on the Facebook side for this and when I try download my own reports using PHP or cURL it works fine.

Comment: I know this is unrelated, but can someone tell me where do I find the ID of async report?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, trying to download the report using request npm in
nodejs.
Adding the User-Agent header solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. You have some issues in your URL string.
Here is an updated url string:

```
    string url = "https://www.facebook.com/ads/ads_insights/export_report?report_run_id=" + report_id + "&format=csv&access_token=" + accessToken;
```

This method works.

```
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        wc.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)";
        wc.DownloadFile(url, "page1.csv");
    }
```

The report gets saved to:

```
C:\your\path\to\project\FacebookReportPuller\bin\Debug
```